# Is it possible to read the content of a Binary File as Dictionary in Python?

Tags: python, matlab, anaconda, binaryfiles

I have raw data files in binary format. While I have written the code earlier in MATLAB, I wanted to transform the same into PYTHON.

I have attached a couple of binary files. My MATLAB code for reading each of these files based on the file format specification document is as below:

---

```
f1 = fopen('p580.004','r')
if (f1 ~= -1)
    must = fread(f1,1,'int16');
    internaltrigger = fread(f1,1,'int8'); 
    internaldwell = fread(f1,1,'int8'); 
    dwellunits = fread(f1,1,'int8'); 
    check_dwell(dwellunits==0)=2;
    check_dwell(dwellunits==1)=0.002;
    check_dwell(dwellunits==2)=0.000002;
    check_dwell(dwellunits==3)=200;
    check_dwell(dwellunits>3)=NaN;
    check_dwell(dwellunits<0)=NaN;
    acqmode = fread(f1,1,'int8'); 
    formatdwell = fread(f1,1,'int32'); 
    passlength = fread(f1,1,'int16');
    passcount = fread(f1,1,'int32');
    passpreset = fread(f1,1,'int32');
    starttime = fread(f1,8,'*char');
    startdate = fread(f1,8,'*char');
    markerchannel = fread(f1,1,'int16');
    mcsno = fread(f1,1,'int8');
    calibtype = fread(f1,1,'int8');
    calibunit = fread(f1,4,'*char');
    calibcoef0 = fread(f1,4,'int8');
    calibcoef1 = fread(f1,4,'int8');
    externaldwelthrevolt = fread(f1,4,'int8');
    reserv1 = fread(f1,1,'int32');
    reserv2 = fread(f1,1,'int8');
    replacethesum = fread(f1,1,'int8');
    identbyte = fread(f1,1,'*char');
    progdwethrevolt = fread(f1,1,'int8');
    detdeslength = fread(f1,1,'int8');
    detdes = fread(f1,63,'*char');
    samplength = fread(f1,1,'int8');
    sampledes = fread(f1,63,'*char');
    lindisflag = fread(f1,1,'int8');
    linscale = fread(f1,1,'int8');
    disstarchannel = fread(f1,2,'int8');
    disnumchannels = fread(f1,1,'int16');
    reser = fread(f1,10,'int8');
    discse = fread(f1,1,'int8');
    discedg = fread(f1,1,'int8');
    discvolt = fread(f1,4,'int8');
    scaupvolt =fread(f1,1,'float32');
    scalolvolt = fread(f1,1,'float32');
    dwelltime = fread(f1,1,'float32');
    setconsflag = fread(f1,1,'int8');
    reserve = fread(f1,13,'int8');
    calibcoef2 = fread(f1,1,'float32');
    calibcoef3 = fread(f1,1,'float32');
    mcsid = fread(f1,8,'*char');
    if (dwelltime == check_dwell) && (length(startdate)>=2)
        x1= fread(f1,1024,'int32'); % Photon Count
        if (isempty(x1) ~= 1) && (length(x1) == 1024) && (length(find(x1>0))>100)
            photoncount(1:1024) = x1;
        else
            photoncount(1:1024) = NaN;
        end
        %%%%%%% converting char array to string %%%%%
        startdate=cell2mat(cellstr(startdate)');
        starttime=cell2mat(cellstr(starttime)');
        %%%%%%% checking for date format %%%%%
        test=find(startdate == '-');
        if (isempty(test) ~=1)
            day2=startdate(1,4:5);
            month2=startdate(1,1:2);
            year2=pfiles1(i).date(8:11);
        else
            if (strcmp(startdate,'') ~=1)
                day2=startdate(1,3:4);
                month2=startdate(1,1:2);
                year2=startdate(1,5:8);
            else
                day2='';
                month2='';
                year2='';
            end
        end
end
```

---

In PYTHON, I wrote the following code:

```
from array import array

fname = 'p580.004'

with open(fname,'rb') as file:

      pdata = array( 'B', file.read() )  # buffer the file
```

The pdata output results the following:

```
pdata = 

Out[1]: array('B', [252, 255, 1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 212, 48, 0, 0, 212, 48, 0, 0, 48, 48, 58, 49, 52, 58, 51, 54, 48, 57, 50, 57, 50, 48, 49, 56, 75, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 11, 70, 179, 63, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 170, 1, 7, 77, 67, 66, 32, 49, 50, 49, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 13, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 225, 183, 15, 191, 255, 245, 31, 65, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 64, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 77, 67, 83, 112, 45, 48, 48, 49, 75, 0, 0, 0, 183, 0, 0, 0, 210, 0, 0, 0, 201, 0, 0, 0, 178, 0, 0, 0, 169, 0, 0, 0, 130, 0, 0, 0, 103, 0, 0, 0, 90, 0, 0, 0, 95, 0, 0, 0, 84, 0, 0, 0, 61, 0, 0, 0, 52, 0, 0, 0, 55, 0, 0, 0, 40, 0, 0, 0, 25, 0, 0, 0, 21, 0, 0, 0, 31, 0, 0, 0, 20, 0, 0, 0, 21, 0, 0, 0, 27, 0, 0, 0, 21, 0, 0, 0, 20, 0, 0, 0, 20, 0, 0, 0, 15, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 0, 0, 16, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0])
```

If I use the following Python code:

```
with open(fname,'rb') as f:  # b is important -> binary
    fileContent = f.read()
```

Now, the fileContent output gives the output in hexadecimal format.

The following are my queries:

1. Is there a way I can read the binary file as a Dictionary in Python?
2. As you see the MATLAB code, there are different formatted variables e.g., int8, int16, int32, char, float32. How to handle these different formats with the Python code I wrote?
3. I have tried to search internet but could not understand how to identify the format of the data in the binary file (assuming you don't have format specification information) and how to assign the actual values to the variables.
4. Can anyone help me convert the MATLAB script to Python code for reading the binary file?

Based on the suggestions, I have revised the code as below:

```
fname = 'p580.004'
with open(fname, 'rb') as fd:
    binbuf = fd.read()

data_names = ('must','internaltrigger','internaldwell','dwellunits', \
              'acqmode','formatdwell','passlength','passcount','passpreset', \
              'starttime','startdate','markerchannel','mcsno','calibtype', \
              'calibunit','calibcoef0','calibcoef1','externaldwelthrevolt', \
              'reserv1','reserv2','replacethesum','identbyte', \
              'progdwethrevolt','detdeslength','detdes','samplength', \
              'sampledes','lindisflag','linscale','disstarchannel', \
              'disnumchannels','reser','discse','discedg','discvolt', \
              'scaupvolt','scalolvolt','dwelltime','setconstflag', \
              'reserve','calibcoef2','calibcoef3','mcsid','Ncount')
data_tuple = struct.unpack_from('hbbbbihii8s8schbb4s4b4b4bibbcbb63pb63cbb2bh10bbb4bfffh13hff8c1024i', binbuf)
```

The main issue I am facing is defining the format of the binary file. There is an inconsistency in the len(binbuf) and the struct.calcsize('hbbbbihii8s8schbb4s4b4b4bibbcbb63pb63cbb2bh10bbb4bfffh13hff8c1024i'). Can anyone suggest me where I am going wrong in the formatting based on the MATLAB code indicated above?

Comment: what's the content of your file 'p580.004' ?

Comment: As you see the MATLAB code, there are different formatted variables e.g., int8, int16, int32, char, float32. How to handle these different formats with the Python code I wrote? For that you can use numpy

Comment: Thanks Hariom Singh. Can you please provide me an example of using numpy to access different formatted variables in the binary files? How can I attach the binary file ('p580.004') for your inspection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could write the PYTHON code using numpy as below:

```
import numpy as np

dt=np.dtype([('must',np.int16),
   ('nternaltrigger',np.int8),
   ('internaldwell',np.int8),
   ('dwellunits',np.int8),
   ('acqmode',np.int8),
   ('formatdwell',np.int32),
   ('passlength',np.int16),
   ('passcount',np.int32),
   ('passpreset',np.int32),
   ('starttime','|S8'),
   ('startdate','|S8'),
   ('markerchannel',np.int16),
   ('mcsno',np.int8),
   ('calibtype',np.int8),
   ('calibunit','|S4'),
   ('calibcoef0','|S4'),
   ('calibcoef1','|S4'),
   ('externaldwelthrevolt',np.int8,(4,)),
   ('reserv1',np.int32),
   ('reserv2',np.int8),
   ('replacethesum',np.int8),
   ('identbyte','|S1'),
   ('progdwethrevolt',np.int8),
   ('detdeslength',np.int8),
   ('detdes','|S63'),
   ('samplength',np.int8),
   ('sampledes','|S63'),
   ('lindisflag',np.int8),
   ('linscale',np.int8),
   ('disstarchannel',np.int8,(2,)),
   ('disnumchannels',np.int16),
   ('reser',np.int8,(10,)),
   ('discse',np.int8),
   ('discedg',np.int8),
   ('discvolt',np.int8,(4,)),
   ('scaupvolt',np.float32),
   ('scalolvolt',np.float32),
   ('dwelltime',np.float32),
   ('setconsflag',np.int8),
   ('reserve',np.int8,(13,)),
   ('calibcoef2',np.float32),
   ('calibcoef3',np.float32),
   ('mcsid','|S8'),
   ('photocount',np.int32,(1024,))])

f=np.fromfile('p580.004',dtype=dt)
d=dict(zip(f.dtype.names,f[0]))
```

This works fine as required. Thanks everyone for the suggestion and initial help.

Answer (score 1):

To read binary data into variable in python3, there is the `struct` module.  It allows to specify  how to interpret the bytes (e.g. unsigned long, signed char, etc.) and in what order by a format string.

E.g. The format string 'hbb' in the call to `struct.unpack_from()` in the examples below means:

- 'h' :  read a 16-bit signed int
- 'b' :  then a 8-bit int
- 'b' :  then another 8-bit int

Quick example to read the first 3 of your variables from a binary file:

```
import struct

fname = 'p580.004'
with open(fname, 'rb') as fd:
    binbuf = fd.read()

must, internaltrigger, internaldwell = struct.unpack('hbb', binbuf)
print('must:', must)
print('internaltrigger:', internaltrigger)
print('internaldwell:', internaldwell)
```

Or, to read the same into a dictionary as you asked:

```
import struct

fname = 'p580.004'
with open(fname, 'rb') as fd:
    binbuf = fd.read()

data_names = ('must', 'internaltrigger', 'internaldwell' )
data_tuple = struct.unpack('hbb', binbuf)
dictionary = dict(zip(data_names, data_tuple))
print(dictionary)
```

For more about this: https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html

Comment: Thank you Hkoof. I still have some issues with formatting. When I define the format for all the variables as mentioned in my MATLAB code as below I still get errors especially while defining the character/strings and the last 1024 integers. Can you suggest me how I can rectify this?

data_tuple = struct.unpack_from('hbbbbihii8s8schbb4s4b4b4bibbcbb63pb63cbb2bh10bbb4bfffh13hff8c1024i', binbuf)

Comment: I can imagine that to be quite a puzzle... It may help to call `struct.calcsize(fmt)` on your format string to see if it the number of bytes expected match you file sizes.

Comment: It is probably more correct to use `struct.unpack()` instead of `struct.unpack_from()` as I used it first. I've edited my post.

Comment: fmt='hbbbbihii8s8schbb4s4b4b4bibbcbb63pb63cbb2bh10bbb4bfffh13hff8c1024i'
The 'struct.calcsize(fmt)' gives a value of 4376 while 'len(binbuf)' gives 4352. The defined format is larger by 24 units. I am not clear on how to rectify this. Where am I going wrong?